# Unable to import tkSnack from Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, import, module, pip

I'm trying to import tkSnack from Python3 in Debian 10.

I have already installed tkSnack from apt:

```
apt-get install python3-tksnack
```

Anyway, when trying to import tkSnack module frome python3:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkSnack'
```

I have also tried to install tkSnack from pip, but the following error message appears:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/cooper/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-x8rnbcp1/snack/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-x8rnbcp1/snack/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-x8rnbcp1/snack/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-x8rnbcp1/snack/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x8rnbcp1/snack/setup.py", line 47
        print GCC_VERSION
                        ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(GCC_VERSION)?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It's strange that, when importing tkSnack in python2.7 all works well!

Does anyone have any idea about this? Thaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're 2 separate problems in your question so it'd be better if you've asked 2 different questions.

1. You installed the package with system package manager `apt-get` but tried to use with local anaconda environment. That doesn't work: packages installed with system package managers should be used with system-installed python. To install packages into virtual environments (including anaconda) use `conda` or `pip`.
2. `SyntaxError` in `print` means the code is for Python2 only; in Python3 `print` becomes a function and requires parenthesizes: `print(GCC_VERSION)`. It seems you installed a wrong, Python2-only version of the package and is trying to use it with Python3. Uninstall it and reinstall with code update for Python3.